# How to combine an image tensor (4D) and a depth tensor (4D) to create a 5D tensor [batch size, channels, depth, height, width] in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, transform, tensor

During training, I load image and disparity data. The image tensor is of shape: [2, 3, 256, 256], and disparity/depth tensor is of shape: [2, 1, 256, 256] (batch size, channels, height, width).
I want to use Conv3D, so I need to combine these two tensors and create a new tensor of shape: [2, 3, 256, 256, 256] (batch size, channels, depth, height, width).
The depth values range from 0-400, and a possibility is to divide that into intervals, e.g., 4 intervals of 100. I want the resulting tensor to look like a voxel, similarly to the technique used in this [paper](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ICCV_2017_workshops/papers/w17/Zia_RGB-D_Object_Recognition_ICCV_2017_paper.pdf). The training loop that iterates over the data is below:

```
 for batch_id, sample in enumerate(train_loader):
        
        sample = {name: tensor.cuda() for name, tensor in sample.items()}

        # image tensor [2, 3, 256, 256]
        rgb_image = transforms.Lambda(lambda x: x.mul(255))(sample["frame"]) 
        
        # translate disparity to depth
        depth_from_disparity_frame = 132.28 / sample["disparity_frame"]
        # depth tensor [2, 1, 256, 256]
        depth_image = depth_from_disparity_frame.unsqueeze(1)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you have a single depth value per scene that means you're dealing with 2D data, not 3D voxels. In order to transition to 3D, you would have to fill in the 3rd dimension a bit like one-hot encodings according to the depth value. Is that what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: I have a single depth value per pixel. As in the paper: "Each RGB-D pixel of an image is then placed at the same position in the voxel grid but at its corresponding depth. This results in a 3D representation that simultaneously encodes the 3D spatial and color information of a given object."  Do you have any idea as to how to fill in the 3rd dimension based on the depth per pixel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the article your linked:

> We create a
> 3D voxel representation, with the same height and width as
> the original image, and with a depth determined by the difference between the maximum and minimum depth values
> found in the images. Each RGB-D pixel of an image is then
> placed at the same position in the voxel grid but at its corresponding depth.

This is what Ivan suggested, more or less. If you know that your depth will always be 0-400 and I imagine that you can skip the first part of "depth determined by the difference between the maximum and minimum depth values". This could always be normalized before-hand or later.

Code using dummy data:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

# Declarations (dummy tensors)
rgb_im = torch.randint(0, 255, [1, 3, 256, 256])
depth = torch.randint(0, 400, [1, 1, 256, 256])

# Calculations
depth_ohe = F.one_hot(depth, num_classes=400)       # of shape (batch, channel, height, width, binary)
bchwd_tensor = rgb_im.unsqueeze(-1)*depth_ohe       # of shape (batch, channel, height, width, depth)
bcdhw_tensor = bchwd_tensor.permute(0, 1, 4, 2, 3)  # of shape (batch, channel, depth, height, width)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was getting an error when trying to use `torch.nn.functional.one_hot` and it worked when I did `depth_ohe = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(depth.to(torch.int64), num_classes=400)`.